# How to display Image Gallery in Android

Tags: android, image

I am new to android development.
My question is i am able to retrieve the data from `sqlite` database.
i am converting the `image` data in to `image`.
I need to retrieve all the images data from database and display as image gallery.
Is there any way to do it.

Below is my code

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.res.TypedArray;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class task1images extends Activity  {
    private Integer[] myImageIds;
     private Gallery gallery;
     private ImageView imgView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.images);     
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
        try{
            Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("select photo from messages where task=1 and photo!=''"  , null);  


            //get the gallery items from the cursor
            ArrayList galleryList = new ArrayList();
            for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                Integer gal;
                gal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("photo"));
                galleryList.add(gal);               
            }
            System.out.println("size:::"+galleryList.size());
            myImageIds =(Integer[])galleryList.toArray(new Integer[galleryList.size()]);
            System.out.println(myImageIds[0]);
            imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            imgView.setImageResource(myImageIds[0]);

            gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
            gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imgView.setImageResource(myImageIds[position]);
            }
            });
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
           Log.e("Error", "Error", e);
          } finally {
           if (myDB != null)
            myDB.close();
          }
    }
    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return myImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

            imgView.setImageResource(myImageIds[position]);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

            return imgView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to write a sql to fetch all the images in DB then as per resultset create a for Loop to create image from each tuple(row).

Comment: Yes, i am able to loop the data but how can i add the data in to gallery.

Comment: Do *not* post the same question twice.  If you have additional details to add to the original question, update *that* question.  Posting the same question twice might result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do looping, you have make an adapter and set it to your gallery 
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html

EDITED:

in getView()

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageFromBLOB(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("fieldname"))));
```

Method: to get Bitmap from Blob

```
public Bitmap getImageFromBLOB(byte[] mBlob) {
    byte[] bb = mBlob;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);

}
```

Edited:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ImageView mImageView;
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inf=mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
                vi=inf.inflate(R.layout.xxxxxx, null);

                mImageView=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgview_row);
                 vi.setTag(mImageView);
            }
             else
                 mImageView=(ImageView)vi.getTag();

            try {

                cursor.moveToPosition(position); 
                mImageView.image.setImageBitmap(AllMethod.getImageFromBLOB(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("fieldname"))));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in this post images were in drawable folder, but i need to convert the data to image from database and display the images in gallary

Comment: @Vamshi: [this might also helpful for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/593709)

Comment: are you storing image path or BLOB in DB?

Comment: @hotveryspicy: hi am storing as blob

Comment: dnt add imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg); directly first see that your source image is coming or not. comment that line and try

Comment: @hotveryspicy: Actually the data is coming as base64string

Comment: c.moveToFirst();
 if (c != null) {int i = 0;
do {i++;  String photo = c.getString(Column1);if(photo!=""){             
byte[] myByteArray = Base64EnCoder.decode(photo);
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myByteArray,0,myByteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.GalleryView);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);byte[] myByteArray1 = Base64EnCoder.decode(photo);
}}while(c.moveToNext());}
it is displaying 1 image only

Comment: with above code i am able to display only 1 image in the screen, not gallery

Comment: your way is little complex, 'm having no time to understand. Better try and google it sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example, it will get blob data into bitmap and you need to set it in imageview which is define in your costume **grid view** :::

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(columnIndex));
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

And Custom Gridview ::

[**1. Developer Example**](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)
[**2. Stealthcopter.com**](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)
[**3. Super android fighter Paresh mayani**](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/09/custom-gridview.html)
[**4. For custom search...**](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&pwst=1&sa=X&ei=u7n5Tq_DKMforQfl8eXLDw&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=custom%20gridview%20in%20android&spell=1&biw=1024&bih=636)

Comment: i am able to read and convert the data but how add the multiple images in gridview

Comment: implement custom adapter concept

Answer (score 0):

To read image from database use something like this:

```
Cursor c = <your db object>.query(...);
while (c.moveToNext())
{
 byte[] image = c.getBlob();
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly i have done this, then how to add multiple images in grid view